# Using angular console plugin in vs code

Tags: angular, angular-console

I installed Angular Console Plugin for VS Code from the link : [Angular Console VS Plugin](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=nrwl.angular-console)

But no where I am able to find on how to start the plugin and I am not able to find the options also.

Can anybody or the team help me in understanding on how to open the plugin from VS Code.

Comment: Did you restart VS Code? If so; you can try to press F1 and type Angular Console.

Comment: Thanks Got it now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once installed the plugin, you just have to press the key (F1), or (Ctrl + Shif + P), or go to the view menu and select the command palette, in the box that you get, type Angular Console and you can use this wonderful plugin.

[command palette](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mOoTp.png)

[Angular console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/poC6B.png)

I hope the answer will help you.